# Why does the NIV have 16 verses missing from the Bible?

Tags: kjv, textual-criticism, niv

Why does the NIV have 16 missing verses from the Bible?

Matthew 17:21
Matthew 18:11
Matthew 23:14

Mark 7:16
Mark 9:44
Mark 9:46.
Mark 11:26.
Mark 15:28

Luke 17:36.

John 5:4

Acts 8:37.
Acts 15:34.
Acts 24:7.
Acts 28:29

Romans 16:24.

1John 5:7

I read from the KJV & I did a side by side to see if what I was told is true. Well, it is. I just want to know why?

Comment: The real question is why does the KJV have 16 extra verses!

Comment: Related: [Why is Acts 8:37 missing in the NIV](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7926/why-is-acts-837-missing-in-the-niv)?

Answer (score 2):

It is NIV (not NLV); and all modern Bible versions contain those differences with the KJV. The reason is that the modern versions are made from more reliable manuscripts than the KJV, which was made from 10th century codex. Here is a whole [series of lecture on Bible](https://bible.org/seriespage/part-iii-kjv-rv-elegance-accuracy) translations by Dan Wallace, that answers this.